# How to get POST headers from Kwik site without downloading the video content?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, http-post

I plan to find the link of the video from Kwik site . The Kwik servers only display the video when referred by an appropriate site so I found a code and modified it to the following code:

```
import requests
import re
down_url='http://kwik.cx/f/DsZh1AuNVGWF'

s=requests.Session()

parts_re = re.compile(r'action=\"([^"]+)\".*value=\"([^"]+)\".*Click Here to Download',re.DOTALL)
kwik_text=s.get(down_url,headers={'referer':down_url}).text

post_url,token=parts_re.search(kwik_text).group(1,2)

url=s.post(post_url,data={'_token':token},headers={'referer':down_url},allow_redirects='False').url
print(url)
```

I When I run this code the script uses around ~150 mb which is the size of the video and then displays the link.

Again I found in someone's code that the url to the video is located in`s.post(post_url,data={'_token':token},headers={'referer':down_url},allow_redirects='False').header['Location']` ,even if though I tried it ,the script still uses ~150 mb and shows a key error

So my question is How do you print the url of the actual video without downloading the video in background ?

Comment: Maybe you can just read the source code using readLines and parse it, without actually requesting the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with the code it seems the site sends a redirect request

```
send: b'_token=ZnuawawUSe1pVvk7iPGi4dvqVEsLe0jWzrFbT3SC'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n'
```

so there was an error in my code `allow_redirects = 'False'` which actually should be a boolean like `allow_redirects = False` and now it works.
The finalised code is:

```
import requests
import re
down_url='http://kwik.cx/f/DsZh1AuNVGWF'

s=requests.Session()

parts_re = re.compile(r'action=\"([^"]+)\".*value=\"([^"]+)\".*Click Here to Download',re.DOTALL)
kwik_text=s.get(down_url,headers={'referer':down_url}).text

post_url,token=parts_re.search(kwik_text).group(1,2)

url=s.post(post_url,data={'_token':token},headers={'referer':down_url},allow_redirects=False).headers['location']
print(url)
```